# Ansible Playbook for Windows or Linux

Tags: ansible

I've created an ansible role that's able to deploy some software on systems that or either Windows or Linux based, but I'm having an issue deploying across both sets of servers simultaneously. The issue that I'm having is for the playbook that I've created that calls the role. The Linux tasks won't run if I don't include `become: true`, and if I do put that into the playbook, the Windows tasks won't run because `{"msg": "The PowerShell shell family is incompatible with the sudo become plugin"}`. An easy fix to the solution is to just include `become: true` for my Linux tasks but I was hoping there's a better way to do it than that. I was thinking about maybe running a conditional `become` (as demonstrated below), but I don't think that would work. Would love to hear your ideas.

**playbook.yml**

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: "{{ 'no' if ansible_facts['os_family'] == 'Windows' else 'yes' }}"
  roles: 
    - /path/to/role
```

Comment: Are your hosts also grouped into "Linux" and "Windows" host groups? If not, can they be? That way you can just have two plays in the one playbook - one with `become: yes` and one without

Comment: Yep, I'm using an inventory plugin to dynamically separate the instances. This is an acceptable answer and it looks like I was way overthinking on how to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Using a conditional for `become` is a nice technique, however you cannot put it in the playbook header as you describe in the question. The variables you use are gathered facts.

This will work:

```yaml
---
- name: Windows and Linux playbook
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:

    - name: Include role
      become: "{{ false if ansible_facts['os_family'] == 'Windows' else true }}"
      ansible.builtin.include_role:
        name: your_role
```